# Fill empt< grid items

Tags: css

I'm trying to sort divs as "cards" on a line with css grid:

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
}

section{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
  align-items: end;
}

article {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


div {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article><div>A<br>B</div></article>
  <article><div>B</div></article>
  <article><div>C</div></article>
  <article><div>D</div></article>
  <article><div>E <br> x</div></article>
  <article><div>F</div></article>
  <article><div>G</div></article>
</section>
```

How can I set the last border-bottom to fill the full viewport width? Is there some way to creae empty grid cells to fill the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pseudo element on the first item of each row:

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
}

section{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
  align-items: end;
}

article {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position:relative;
}
article:nth-child(3n + 1)::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  height:2px;
  left:0;
  /* cover the two columns on the right */
  right:-200%;  /* OR width:300% */
  background:#000;
}


div {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article><div>A<br>B</div></article>
  <article><div>B</div></article>
  <article><div>C</div></article>
  <article><div>D</div></article>
  <article><div>E <br> x</div></article>
  <article><div>F</div></article>
  <article><div>G</div></article>
</section>
```

Comment: Temani Afif, one more little question. if I have five items in a row how would I need to change the pseudo before selector?

Comment: @tBook you use -400% ... it's (n - 1)*-100% ... or you can use width:500% (n*100%)